# Enabling printing feature within the Terminal Server environment that is published to the internet?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-terminal-services

I got the home and remote office users connect to the Terminal Server on my Windows Server 2003 that I published securely through Juniper SSL VPN client applet, they use normal internet connection to access the link which pop up the Terminal Server Remote Desktop application, so my question is, how can they print out the document from within their terminal server session ?

if it is going through the internal office LAN mapping the printer through Remote Desktop connection is the solution but not for this one.

Any kind of help and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks